# excel formula to give the priority to a value from a range of values in a column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

This is probably a simple fix (although me thinking this, means it probably isn't), so I apologize in advance if this is mere child's play.

In an excel sheet I am working on, I have a range (for the sake of this example is B1:B10) which can contain one of 5 variables (not including blanks) - OG, D, L, PP or C.

I require a formula in another cell to review the range in question and output a value based on the following rules in this priority:

1. If OG appears anywhere in the column, regardless of other inputs, display OG;
2. If D and L and/or PP and/or C appear in the column, display OG;
3. If only D appears in the column, display D;
4. If only PP appears in the column, display PP;
5. If only L appears in the column, display L;
6. If only C appears in the column, display C; and
7. If all cells within the column are blank, display blank

For rules 1-6, any blank cells within the column should not be considered. It is only where all cells are blank, i.e. rule 7, that this should be considered.

I have tried IF formulas but have found these only consider a single cell. 
I've tried searching everywhere and can't find anything on this (although this is probably down to me not phrasing my question/searches correctly).

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use an 'if' formula, but for your condition, Use 'MATCH': for eg, for checking the first case:

```
=IF(MATCH("OG",$B$1:$B$10,0), "OG", "FALSE")
```

The above formula will put "OG" if it's in any of the cells, else "FALSE".
In a similar way, change all your logic, but set the conditions to use match to see if they exist somewhere in the column

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution. For your 6 first tests, you type each of these formulas in a cell (I did it from D1 to D6) :

Test 1 (D1)

```
=IF(COUNTIF(B1:B10;"OG");"OG";"")
```

Test 2 (D2)

```
=IF(AND(COUNTIF(B1:B10;"D");OR(COUNTIF(B1:B10;"L");COUNTIF(B1:B10;"C");COUNTIF(B1:B10;"C";"")));"OG";"")
```

Test 3 (D3)

```
=IF(COUNTIF(B1:B10;"D")=DCOUNTA(B1:B10);"D";"")
```

Do the same for test 4 to 6 by replacing "D" by "P","L","C".

Now your target cell :

```
=IF(D7="empty";"";INDEX(D1:D7;MATCH(TRUE;INDEX((D1:D7<>"");0);0)))
```

This last cell will simply show the first non empty value of your test cells.
The last test is kind of implicit.

I hope I got your tests right, let me know if not.

EDIT : Sorry for the numerous editings, my Office isn't in English, that's a pain to translate the formulas. They should be working now.

EDIT 2 : Your last test is not implicit and there is a possibility that last cell show "NA". So you should add this to D7 :

```
=IF(COUNT(B1:B10)=0;"empty";"*A value to show if all tests didn't pass*")
```

Also now your target cell has D7 in its formula's range.

Answer (score 0):

I feel condition 2 little confusing, Do you mean D is mandatory and other (L,PP,C) are option to result "OG" ?

What should be the result if we have multiple input of (L,PP,C) in the range ? Should it be BLANK?

I came up with this formula if D is mandatory in condition 2 and formula will return Blank if only other 3 inputs are there except "OG" and "D"

Formula: `=IF(COUNTIF(B1:B10,"OG")>0,"OG",IF(AND(COUNTIF(B1:B10,"D")>0,SUM(COUNTIF(B1:B10,"D"),COUNTIF(B1:B10,"L"),COUNTIF(B1:B10,"PP"),COUNTIF(B1:B10,"C"))>1),"OG",IF(COUNTIF(B1:B10,"D")=COUNTA(B1:B10),"D",IF(COUNTIF(B1:B10,"L")=COUNTA(B1:B10),"L",IF(COUNTIF(B1:B10,"PP")=COUNTA(B1:B10),"PP",IF(COUNTIF(B1:B10,"C")=COUNTA(B1:B10),"C",""))))))`

First Condition:

[image: First Condition:]

Condition 2:

[image]

Condition 3:

[image]

Condition 4:

[image]

Condition 5:If there is no "OG" or "D" in the array formula returns Blank.

[image]